# position of element in a list using a function

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I find in a list `l` the positions of all elements satisfying a boolean function `f`.

For example, how can I pick in `{1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1}` the first element that does not equal `1`?

A minimized version of an aswer (short code) is welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list = {1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1}

(* get position of first non-one *)
Position[list, _?(# != 1 &), 1, 1]

(* get positions of all non-one *)
Position[list, _?(# != 1 &)]

(* get value of first non-one *)
First@Cases[list, _?(# != 1 &)]

(*
{{4}}

{{4},{5},{6},{8},{11}}

3
*)
```

Many other ways (see, e.g. `Pick`, `Except`, `Select` for a start ... )

For your arbitrary function `f`, just use it in constructs like above, e.g.:

```
Position[list, _?f]
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not familiar with `_?`, this seems really slick. So this is a way to turn a boolean expression into a pattern? Can't find `_?` in the Mathematica 6 manual...

Comment: @LeonLampret: As I said, there are *many* ways to do this kind of thing, I'm sure you'll see others in answers. See [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternTest.html) for the pattern test (`?`) info. You might also look at [condition](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html), another way this kind of thing can be done.

Comment: @Leon Lampret - maybe a little bit easier to read for us starters: First@Position[list, a_ /; a != 1]

Comment: @eldo: Why doesn't your or rasher's code work:
`n=3;
l={{2,1,3},{1,3,2}};
Position[l, _?(#[[n]]!=n&), 1, 1]
First@Position[l, a_ /; a[[n]]!=n]`
It should return $2$.

Comment: @LeonLampret: Do this `Position[l, _?((Sow[#]; #[[n]] != n) &), 1, 1] // Reap` ... observe the result. Now, try this `Position[l, _?(#[[n]] != n &), 1, 1, Heads -> False]` for your sublist case. Reply back if not clear *why* this is...

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1};
```

Some alternatives to `Position`:

```
f = (# != 1 &) (* say *)
Pick[Range[Length@list], f /@ list]
(* {4,5,6,8,11} *)

Select[Range[Length@list], f@list[[#]] &]
(* {4,5,6,8,11} *)

Select[Range[Length@list], f@list[[#]] &, 1]
(* {4} *)

Join@@ MapIndexed[If[f@#, #2, ## &[]] &, list]  (* credit for ##&[]: Mr.W and ?? *)
(* {4,5,6,8,11} *)

Catch@MapIndexed[If[f@#, Throw[#2]] &, list]
(* {4} *)
```